# How to add multiple texts on Visio connector shapes using the c#/vba code?

Tags: c#, vba, visio

I want to add multiple texts on the connector line as per the image below. I am using c# code to automate the process. Below is my code which I have used. It is not giving the exact output as I had expected. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

```
Visio.Shape vsoLastShape = visioPage.Shapes.get_ItemFromID(lastshapeID);
vsoLastShape.ConvertToGroup();
                            
Visio.Selection vsoSelections = app.ActiveWindow.Selection;
vsoSelections.Select(vsoLastShape, (short)VisSelectArgs.visSelect);

Visio.Shape vsoGroupShape = vsoSelections.Group();

vsoGroupShape.Text = "Testing 12";
vsoGroupShape.TextStyle.PadLeft(10);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whatever method (manual, C#, VBA or whatevber) you use, one shape can only contain one text. If you want to add more than one text then you need to convert the shape into a grouped shape. Then you can add a shape to the group and set that sub-shape's text to what you want.

Comment: I have doing the same this in my code to convert the shape to a group but while adding text to the group it will not work. Can you suggest the issue with my code as it is not working as i expect.

Comment: Your code is now grouping twice, a ConvertToGroup() and a Group(). You don't need the .Group(). Set vsoGroupShape as the result of the ConvertToGroup. Then add a new shape to the page, call it, say, vsoNewShape, set its text and location, then add it to the group.

Answer (score 0):

Shape .Characters object used in conjunction with .Text allows for some flexibility.

```
    private string nl = Environment.NewLine;
    public void MultiText() {
    try {
        // using = System.Windows.Forms;
        // using Vis = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

        Vis.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application; // or launch Visio 
        Vis.Document vDoc = app.Documents.Add(""); // new blank document

        Vis.Shape c1 = app.ActivePage.DrawOval(1, 1, 1.5, 1.5);
        Vis.Shape s1 = app.ActivePage.DrawLine(1.5, 1.25, 4, 1.25);
        s1.Text = $"Shape1{nl}Line2";
        Vis.Shape c2 = app.ActivePage.DrawOval(4, 1, 4.5, 1.5);

        Vis.Shape c3 = app.ActivePage.DrawOval(1, 3, 1.5, 3.5);
        Vis.Shape s2 = app.ActivePage.DrawLine(1.5, 3.25, 4, 3.25);
        s2.Text = $"Shape2";
        Vis.Shape c4 = app.ActivePage.DrawOval(4, 3, 4.5, 3.5);
        
        app.ActiveWindow.CenterViewOnShape(c4, Vis.VisCenterViewFlags.visCenterViewDefault);
        app.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 1.2;
        app.ActiveWindow.Selection.DeselectAll();
        app.DoCmd((short)VisUICmds.visCmdDeselectAll);

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"2 Shapes with text.", "Continue...");

        // reset the Text on Shape #2 and define 2 separate ranges
        s2.Text = "";
        // alocate a range 
        Characters range1 = s2.Characters;
        range1.Begin = 0;
        range1.End = 3;
        range1.Text = "Name";
        // alocate another
        Characters range2 = s2.Characters;
        range2.Begin = 4;
        //range2.End = 7;
        range2.Text = $"{Environment.NewLine}Type";

        MessageBox.Show($"Now change Font Size", "Continue...");
        // change font size or any of numerous properties 
        range1.CharProps[(short)Vis.VisCellIndices.visCharacterSize] = 16;
        range2.CharProps[(short)Vis.VisCellIndices.visCharacterSize] = 8;
        //range2.CharProps[(short)Vis.VisCellIndices.visCharacterStrikethru] = 1; // 1-true 0-false

        MessageBox.Show($"Big Name!{nl}little Type.", "OK to continue");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ta.LogIt($"Err {ex.Message} Trace {ex.StackTrace}");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this post and used the uploaded stencil. (Requires registration to see and download the attachment):
http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=6318.msg25957#msg25957